# Laravel - order by relationship table

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have 2 tables `issues` and `magazines` and they have a relationship set up like this:

Magazines model:

```
 public function issues()
 {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Issue');
 }
```

Issues model:

```
public function magazine()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Magazine');
}
```

In the magazines table I have a column `order` where the order number of the magazine is. I need to display the latest issue of each magazine, ordered by the magazine order.
Now I am displaying latest issue of each magazine ordered by the date of issues.

```
        $issues = Issue::orderBy('date', 'desc')->get()->groupBy('magazine_id');

        foreach ($issues->first() as $issue)
        {
            $images[] = $issue->image;
        }
```

And that works fine.
But with the new query:

```
         $magazines = Magazine::with('issues')->orderBy('order')->get();


        foreach ($magazines as $magazine)
        {
            $issues = $magazine->issues()->first();
            $images[] = $magazine->issues()->first()->image;
        }
```

I get the error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Check that `$magazine->issues()->first()` is not returning null before you do `$magazine->issues()->first()->image`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if issue `is_null`, if not, add the image to `$images`:

```
    foreach ($magazines as $magazine)
    {
        $issue = $magazine->issues()->first();
        if (!is_null($issue) {
            $images[] = $issue->image;
        }
    }
```